# How to connect to a Java Socket from a Dartlang Socket

Tags: java, tcp, dart

I have a TCP Server written in java.  I am trying to connect to it via a TCP client socket written in dartlang but the client written in dartlang times out almost immediately after the initial connection (my five second timeout set in the java code).  I *was* able to send a message to the dart client in a test immediately after it connected but it soon timed out.  However the data in the dartlang `'{"packet_id":1}'` never gets received by the server.

I tried writing a test server in dartlang and it was able to connect and send/receive messages without any issues.

Dart Client:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

main(List<String> arguments) {


  Future<Socket> future = Socket.connect('localhost', 12345);
  future.then((client) {
    print('connected to server!');
    client.handleError((data){
      print(data);
    });
    client.listen(
            (data) {
              print(new String.fromCharCodes(data));
            },
            onDone:(){
              print("Done");},
            onError: (error) {
              print(error);
            }
          );
    String requestHalls = '{"packet_id":1}';
    client.write(requestHalls);
  }).catchError(() {print('Error connecting');});
  print('Hello world: ${dart_test.calculate()}!');
}
```

My Java client connects to the Java Server socket just fine.

EDIT: adding java code

creating the serversocket.

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        // Create Server Socket for clients to connect to
        try {
            // load data from config manager
            ConfigManager config = HDAServer.getConfigManager();
            int port = config.getServerPort();
            String ip = config.getServerURL();
            Inet4Address inet4 = (Inet4Address) Inet4Address.getByName(ip); // this allows for binding to domain name or ipv4 address
            HDAServer.getLogger().info(String.format("Opening Server Socket at address(%s)=  %s:%s", ip, inet4.getHostAddress(), port));
            // attempt to bind
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(config.getServerPort(), 50, inet4);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // wait for incoming client connections
        waitForConnections();

    }

    /**
     * Method that waits for incoming connections, adds the connection to a new pool, and creates a
     * new thread for the connection to run on.
     */
    private void waitForConnections() {
        // loop through waiting for incoming connections until server shuts down
        while (!shutdown) {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                // blocks thread waiting for a connection
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (e.getMessage().equals("socket closed")) {
                    HDAServer.getLogger().info("Shutting Down Server Socket");
                    continue;// skip to while check
                } else {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // create our connection class, start it in a new thread, and add it to our connection list
            HDAServerConnection newConn = new HDAServerConnection(socket);
            new Thread(newConn).start();
            connections.add(newConn);
            HDAServer.getLogger().info(String.format("Client connected from: %1s", newConn.getRemoteIP()));
            // reap dead connections
            this.reapDeadConnections();
        }
    }
```

Servers "Client" HDAConnection class:

```
protected Socket socket;
protected DataInputStream inputStream;
protected DataOutputStream outputStream;
private boolean shutdown = false;

public HDAConnection(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;

    // configure socket
    try {
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        AbstractHDALogger.get().severe("Error configuring Socket Connection.", ex);
    }

    // create input/output stream for handling data
    try {
        inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        AbstractHDALogger.get().severe("Error creating input/output streams.", ex);
    }
}
```

code that is listening for a message over the stream.

```
String response = null;
try {
    response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).readLine();
} catch(SocketTimeoutException ste) {
    shutdown();
    AbstractHDALogger.get().severe(String.format("Socket Timed out(%s), closing Connection", this.getRemoteIP()), ste);
    // TODO: handle exception
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Make this better?
    // IO Exception probably means client disconnected, so we should terminate.
    if (e.getMessage().equals("Connection reset")) {
        shutdown();
        AbstractHDALogger.get().info(String.format("Client Connection Disconnected(%s). Closing connection.", this.getRemoteIP()));
    } else {
        shutdown();
        AbstractHDALogger.get().severe(String.format("Connection Error(%s), closing Connection", this.getRemoteIP()), e);
    }   
    return null;
}
```

Comment: And your Java server code?

Comment: If the Java client connects "just fine" to the Java server but the Dartlang client does not, then you have a configuration issue in the Dartlang client, either the hostname or port is wrong.  Another thing to consider is whether or not the client actually _does_ connect but then hangs in your code after connection.  Have you checked for that?

Comment: No you haven't. There is no Java server code here. A Java server would create a `ServerSocket` or `ServerSocketChannel`, and call `accept()`. NB You should not create a new `BufferedReader` per message, and you don't need that *and* a `DataInputStream`: in any case they will never work together.

Comment: I updated with the ServerSocket class for reference that creates the Socket class connection with the client. In any case, I figured out the issue and posted an answer. Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The socket is timing out on the Java Server because the dartlang client is never writing a newline at the end of its message and the Java Server is using the [readline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) method to read.  This function will only return when it reads a new line character.  After reading the initial message from the dartlang client the Java server waits five seconds for more data to be sent but will time out as nothing more is ever sent.

The dartlang client should use the [writeln](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/IOSink/writeln.html) function or appent a newline character to the end of its messages for the Java server BufferedReader to return.

Comment: @ayyron_Imao I am getting similar error. What is the best way from Dart to close java server connection? In my Dart code I also use  \n. but I am keep getting error connection reset by peer errno 104 SocketException. I can get data first time and if I try to get second time I get this error. If I wait bit longer and try to get I get data with above error